# make a layout occupy only fraction of its view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout-weight

suppose I want to get this result:
[image]

Currently, my approach in XML is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/llWRAPER"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/llspacer_left"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llMAINCONTENT"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llspacer_right"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Paraphrasing: I have a wrapper layout and then 3 linear layouts with weight 1 in order to achieve this effect. I wanted to know if there is a cleaner approach to this. 
Keep in ming I need exactly 1/3 of the parent View ocuppied by the main content and I want it to be centered.
If possible please give XML answers since getting the width and setting the size programatically is a good option, but I like working my visuals in XML and everything else in Java (unless working in visuals in Java is unavoidable).

Comment: If you're only using XML and you want the views to be always proportional regardless of the actual screen size then layout weight is pretty much the only way to go. You can also add  android:weightSum to your parent view, in this case android:weightSum="3".

Comment: haha, it is funny this is the correct way to do it, thank you Alexi, thumbs up c: